# Easily swap double/float in Java

Tags: java, precision

I have a Java program that throws around a lot of real numbers.

I have two modes in which I'd like to be able to compile it.

- In "accurate" mode, I want to use double-precision for all my real numbers.
- In "fast" mode, I want to use single-precision.

Is there some way I can globally swap all my `double`'s for `float`'s with a single flag?  Currently, I'm using "find and replace", which can't be the best way of doing things.

Edit: Since some have suggested templates/generics, I'll add one further requirement: Efficiency.  From my understanding, a big-F `Float` is a reference to a value, whereas a small-f, primitive `float` is just the value, so it is more time and memory efficient to work with primitives, especially when dealing with big arrays of them (which I am).  And templates/generics can't be used with primitives.  So Id like to find a solution that doesn't require sacrificing efficiency (as that would defeat the original purpose of this whole question).  Unless I'm mistaken and there is some way to do this with templates and primatives.

---

CONCLUSION SO FAR (21:00 28 Dec 2015): There is no satisfactory way, just use double.

- Using any wrapper is unsatisfactory because it leads to an array of pointers, which is inefficient.

Comment: There is no `typedef` and `ifdef` in java...(that would have helped). But you can start bby creating a template

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a [*strategy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Create an interface (or maybe an abstract class) that is a model for real numbers:

```
public interface RealNumber {
    // Define needed methods here!
}
```

Then you create at least two implementations for that interface:

```
public final class AccurateRealNumber implements RealNumber {
    private final double number;
    public AccurateRealNumber(double number) { this.number = number; }
    // Implement interface methods here!
}

public final class LazyRealNumber implements RealNumber {
    private final float number;
    public LazyRealNumber(float number) { this.number = number; }
    // Implement interface methods here!
}
```

You then use only variables of type `RealNumber` whose instances can either be `LazyRealNumber` or `AccurateRealNumber` - your choice.

You have to declare the methods that you need to work with in the interface, so that you can call them on variables of that interface type. Those methods should contain the domain logic that you are using to solve the domain logic. They should *not* return the value (although they could), as these values are of different types.

Comment: How are you suggesting to create the required common methods if for one class they need to be all expressed in `float` parameters and return values and for the other they all need to be expressed in `double` parameters and return values?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well ... the methods should not use `float` or `double` values. They should express the logic that the program is developped for. I edited my answer to say a bit more. I know that this is a difficult task.

Comment: If you don't pass the values to these classes, and you don't take the values back, and you put the entire logic into the method - then you have to write all the logic twice. I don't see, then, how this solves the OP's problem (of copy-pasting everything).

Comment: My answer may provide slightly more info on method definition but this is essentially correct.

Comment: Thanks.  But it seems that this is just reimplementing the functionality of big-F `Float` and `Double`.  I added a comment about why it't not preferable to put a reference in between my program and my values (basically time/memory efficiency) but please correct me if I'm mistaken in my understanding here.

Answer (score 2):

You do not gain as much speed or memory efficiency using floats than double (wordsize is nowadays 64 bit and double is also 64 bit).

Comment: This should be a comment to the question, not posted as an answer. If you haven't gained enough reputation to post a comment, refrain from posting and instead answer a few questions properly to gain the required reputation.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe over-engineering but how about you use dependency injection of objects ?

For example you could define two separate objects which essentially just wrap floats and and doubles. The structure I am thinking of:

```
public class FastNumber implements MyNumber<Float>{
    private Float number;
    ...
}
public class AccurateNumber implements MyNumber<Double>{
    private Double number;
    ...
}
public interface MyNumber<T>{
    //Methods to access and mutate number
    addToNumber(T num);
    subtractFromNumber(T num);
}
```

Since they borth implement the same interface you can change your code to just work with that interface then you can dependency inject `FastNumber` or `AccurateNumber` in as needed based on a simple configuration. For example using [spring boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) or just plain [spring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm). Again this maybe over-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach would be to create a template of the classes which contain the variables whose type you would like to change dynamically. Then you would be able to pass in any type you like based on what mode you want to use.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this would require using big-F Float rather than the primitive float (and the same for Double), which is less efficient memory and time wise (as an array of Floats is an array of pointers to values, rather than just an array of values).  Since I gather Java's Generics don't support primitives, I was hoping there was some other way.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as this

```
public class NumberCoverter {
public static enum ModeType { ACCURATE, FAST }; 
public ModeType modeType = ModeType.ACCURATE;//the default  
public double[] doubleValues = { 7254.22222455879789, 356798.365484464, 15464.48486495615 };    
public float[] floatValues = new float[doubleValues.length] ; //make this array the same size as doubleValues array 
public void printValues(){

    if(modeType==ModeType.ACCURATE)
        printAccurate();
    else
        printFast();

}
public void printAccurate(){

    for(int i=0; i<doubleValues.length;i++)
        System.out.println("Double precision: "+doubleValues[i]);
}
public void printFast(){
    for(int i=0; i<floatValues.length;i++) {
        floatValues[i] = (float)doubleValues[i];
        System.out.println("Single precision: "+floatValues[i]);    
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    NumberCoverter nc = new NumberCoverter();

    System.out.println("Printing in accurate mode");
    nc.printAccurate();

    System.out.println("Printing in fast mode");
    nc.printFast();

}
```

}

For simplicity, class members are all public and arrays are of fixed size, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: TypeCasting is not what I'm looking for.